# How androids "sign into wifi-network" feature works in wifi networks where captive web based login is enabled?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

In general for  captive web portal based login networks, if we type any url in browser it should take to hotspot providers captive web server login page. But when I tried in chrome browser, sometimes browser based redirect is not working. It is displaying webpage not found error message. where as sign into wifi-network always able redirect to operators captive web login page. Can anyone explain the steps behind sign into-wifi network and how it redirects to captive web server. Thank you